# Fusionchart custom message display inside the canvas

Tags: javascript, php, xml, fusioncharts

I need to display message inside the fusionchart (I use Bar 2D Chart). I checked the API but I couldn't.

I need pass the xml message (I attached the image)

Can you please help me.
(gray color is the boarder of the chart)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any way I found a way to implement this, but it used js (not using xml).

```
http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/WzNKT/
```

This url help me lot, thank for the developer.

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts( "FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", 
      "myChartId", "400", "300", "0" );
      myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
      myChart.render("chartContainer");


function myChartListener(eventObject, argumentsObject) {
    myChart.ref.showChartMessage("Hello... the world ends here, take a peek before its gone!", true);
    }
 myChart.addEventListener ("rendered" , myChartListener );
```

When this message display it effect some black background color (like below image)

[image]

If you want to change the style of the message or background color then you can change the css of SVG

```
.xxxxx div span svg rect { 
    fill-opacity: 0;
}
.xxxxx div span svg g rect { 
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
.xxxxx div span svg text tspan {
    fill: black;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

(This css to get same as top image)