# What is the recommended way to show on a chart that the browser is waiting for data?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I'm using FusionChart, more especially the Candlestick chart.

I'm loading data through JSON object that I get with Ajax technologies.

When I've a chart already loaded and I request form new data with dynamics filters, what is the recommended way to show to the user that the old chart doesn't fit my filters anymore?

- Is there a way to add a text : *"Chart is loading... Please wait"* on the middle of the chart?
- Or is there a way to blur all the chart to make it unreadable?
- Is there an option to hide the chart? (there is a function `isActive()` but I don't found any function `setVisible()`)
- Or any idea?

Ideally it wouln't hide the chart space...

Comment: absolute positioned div above the chart with a message or spinner that  hides as soon as the new chart is drawn

Comment: There is no recommended way to deliver what a design and/or ux profiling would define. What way fits best with how your site looks?

Comment: @DavidBarker I wrote them by my preference order. I'm currently testing some tips founded [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058365/fusionchart-custom-message-display-inside-the-canvas) on SE.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is no recommended way. But you can have a div over the chart, which says, "Chart is loading" and you can hide this div once your chart is rendered.  You can listen for the chart rendered event or draw completed event of the chart and hide this loading div.

[Chart Render Completed Event](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/FusionCharts.events.html#event:renderComplete)

[Draw Complete Event of Chart](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/FusionCharts.events.html#event:drawComplete)